# Angular http get return undefined

Tags: angular

I have a express router get

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Stats = require('../models/Stats.js');

/* GET ALL STATS */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Stats.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
  });
});
```

Also api

```
 getAll(){
    this.http.get('/main').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
  }
```

And i am using it in component

```
show(){
      console.log(this.api.getAll());
   }
```

Problem is that when i log data in api getAll() data is returned well, but if i log data in component i have undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service or API within Angular should just be calling the backend service and not subscribing via in the service itself but rather in the component.

Service:

```
getAll(){
  return this.http.get('/main');
}
```

Component:

```
this.service.getAll().subscribe((data)=> {
   // Your Data
},error => {
   console.log('error: ', error)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In `getAll()` you should return the observable:

```
getAll(){
   return this.http.get('/main');
}
```

And then in where you call the function you subscribe to the observable:

```
show(){
  this.api.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
       // Here you can do what you want with the data.
       console.log(data)
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service should `return`, change your service to

```
getAll(){
    return this.http.get('/main').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
  }
```

And it is better to `subscribe` in the component part not while declaring your services.

Comment: Now the `show()` function is only going to log the observable returned by `getAll()`.

Comment: @mika what ?? you're wrong ! it is already subscribed there why would it return observable ??, reread what i'd written.